# Scala Spark - Mapping values of tuple to single

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to map some data looking like this: `("en",(20340,302))` (so a tuple of a string and a tuple: `(String, (Int, Int))` ) into data looking like this: `(String, Int/Int)` (so the example output would be `("en", 67 )` ). What is the syntax for this?

`val new = old.map(a,(b,c) => (a, b/c) )`

is what I tried to do, is not working though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val new = old.map { case (a,(b,c)) => (a, b/c) }
```

Which is syntactic sugar for:

```
val new = old.map(t => t match {
  case (a,(b,c)) => (a, b/c)
})
```

or an uglier version:

```
val new = old.map(t => (t._1, t._2._1/t._2._2))
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. What exactly does the `case` keyword do?

Comment: Edited to clarify - the case keyword is part of the _pattern matching_ syntax, but the `match` keyword can be omitted when applied to a single input argument of an anonymous function